# How to use progressbar to show estimated time left?

Tags: python, loops, progress-bar

Below is a script that extracts URLs and finds out their status codes. Using the package [progressbar](https://pypi.org/project/progressbar), I was able to get a progress bar thanks to the function `pbar()`. However, I would also like to have how much time is left to appear. How can I use the package [progressbar](https://pypi.org/project/progressbar) to show how much time is left based on the number of iterations?

```
link = "https://pastebin.com/raw/hC5ZCQxc"
links = []

t = requests.get(link).text
urls = re.findall(r'http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+', t)

for url in urls:
    links.append(f"{url}")

for url in pbar(links):
    download = requests.get(url)
    status_code = download.status_code
    results.append((url, status_code))
```

Comment: https://github.com/niltonvolpato/python-progressbar/blob/master/examples.py If you want a simple way to show a progress bar only using iterations I would recommend using tqdm package https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm

Comment: Andrew, thank you for your response! I looked at the examples, and they were manual. They aren't based on iterations. Like in the script above, you can see I just had to enclose the list with `pbar()`, and progressbar did the rest. Is there an equivalent for `pbar()` that gives ETA? Thank you. (I also appreciate the tqdm recommendation, definitely checking it out!)

Comment: https://progressbar-2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ There is an ETA section unsure as to how to use it (sorry not what I use)